# Magento 2: Does, and Should, the `crontab` Area Have its own di.xml

Tags: php, magento2, configuration, cron, object-manager

Does Magento 2's `crontab` area load a scoped `di.xml` file?  Or is this no longer used?  Or **should** it be used, but its not being loaded as part of the `crontab` application is a bug?  Or do I fundamentally misunderstand something?

In Magento 2, the "areas" feature allows you to load extra configuration information based on the request context (that's a little hand wavy, but accurate from a certain point of view).

For example, Magento will **always** load the following `di.xml`

```
./vendor/magento/module-tax/etc/di.xml
```

but will only load the following `di.xml` when in the frontend area

```
./vendor/magento/module-tax/etc/frontend/di.xml
```

It's not clear if this is true for the `di.xml` files for the `crontab` area.

The cron runner in Magento is a separate Magento System Application from the Magento System Application that handles HTTP requests.  When the cron application launches, its Magento System Application has a very minimal `launch`

```
#File: vendor/magento/framework/App/Cron.php
public function launch()
{
    $this->_state->setAreaCode('crontab');
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('default');
    $this->_response->setCode(0);
    return $this->_response;
}
```

You can see the call to `setAreaCode` where the `crontab` area code is set. This ensures that requests for configuration trees will merge in any configuration located in a module's `etc/crontab` folder

```
app/etc/crontab/*.xml
```

**However** -- `di.xml` is different/special.  Because Magento needs access to the object manager earlier than the launch of the Magento system application, the object manager initially loads all the `etc/di.xml` files before the call to `setAreaCode`.

During an **HTTP** request, the Magento System Application (`Magento\Framework\App\Http`) loads the area specific `di.xml` files after setting the area code

```
#File: vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php
public function launch()
{
    $areaCode = $this->_areaList->getCodeByFrontName($this->_request->getFrontName());
    $this->_state->setAreaCode($areaCode);
    $this->_objectManager->configure($this->_configLoader->load($areaCode));
    //...
}
```

Since this call to `configure` is missing from the cron Application's `launch` method, it **seems** like the `crontab` doesn't load any `etc/crontab/di.xml` files.  However, there are a few `etc/crontab/di.xml` files present.

```
$ find . -wholename '*crontab/di.xml'
./vendor/magento/module-captcha/etc/crontab/di.xml
./vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule-configurable/etc/crontab/di.xml
```

This creates some confusion about what the correct behavior of the system should be.  Has anyone here been following Magento 2 development closely enough to know what the correct system behavior is?

Comment: basing on all you've described, it should load crontab area. We'll look deeper into it and fix, if necessary. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on feedback from the core team, it sounds like the current behavior is **not** the intended behavior, and in future versions the crontab application will load in a crontab area's `di.xml`.

Comment: Aaaaaaaand...? This still seems broken as of 2.1.5

Comment: Also it doesn't work in 2.2.7...

Comment: `crontab/di.xml` seems to be correctly read in 2.4.3-p2 at least :)